# How to get detailed debugging information from ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

Is there a way to get Arango to tell me why it's giving me a 404? Anytime it doesn't like something I do, the only hint I get is a 404. For example, if I spell a method wrong I would except it would be able to tell me where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404s are usually the result of mount-time errors that prevent the app from being mounted. These errors are usually logged to ArangoDB's log file, including full stack traces if available.

For Linux the logs are stored in `/var/logs`.

Comment: Perfect! On OS X using brew the logs are stored under /usr/local/var/log/arangodb